# Lock that will allow multiple readers in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking

I have the following code:

```
private static object _dbLock = new object();

public static void LoadData()
{
   lock (_dbLock)
   {
      //Load data from the database
   }
}

public static string ReadData(Guid key)
{
   lock (_dbLock)
   {
      //Lookup key in data and return value
   }
}
```

I don't want to allow people to read the data while it's being loaded from the database, thus I put a `lock` in `ReadData`.  However, right now if multiple people call `ReadData` at the same time, only one call can run at once.

Is there a way I can allow simultaneous calls to `ReadData` but block readers when `LoadData` is being run?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [`ReaderWriterLock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock.aspx) and [`ReaderWriterLockSlim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx) classes support that use case.  Use the 'Slim' version unless you need pre-3.5 support.

```
private static ReaderWriterLockSlim _cacheLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

public static void LoadData()
{
    _cacheLock.EnterWriteLock();
    try
    {
        // Load data from the database
    }
    finally
    {
        _cacheLock.ExitWriteLock();
    }
}

public static string ReadData(Guid key)
{
    _cacheLock.EnterReadLock();
    try
    {
        // Lookup key in data and return value
    }
    finally
    {
        _cacheLock.ExitReadLock();
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks perfect!  I figured there'd be something like this in the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `ManualResetEvent`:

```
private static object _dbLock = new object();
private static ManualResetEvent _mrse = new ManualResetEvent(true);

public static void LoadData()
{

   lock (_dbLock)
   {
      _mrse.Reset();
      //Load data from the database
      _mrse.Set();
   }
}

public static string ReadData(Guid key)
{
    _mrse.Wait();
    //Lookup key in data and return value
}
```

This allows multiple readers to wait for the data loader to finish its work and then simultaneously read. If the collection is not thread safe, then you need to add another locking object or use another synchronization construct.

Comment: This is a good answer as well, though I *believe* if someone called `LoadData()` while data was being read, there could potentially be some issues.  I want everything to be blocked while data is being loaded.

Comment: @MikeChristensen good point, as you pointed out: this is just an alternative which might work with some tinkering.